# span multiline start from same position

Tags: html, css

i have html code like this :

```
<span style="color:#c9caca">Scope of Work</span><span class="ga_sep"></span><span>Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine Advertising, Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine, Advertising, Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine Advertising</span>
```

and result is

[image]

but i want this :

[image]

means line 2 in span start from position same line one .

this is my css code but not work :

```
.ga_sep{
    height:10px;
    width:1px;
    border-left:1px solid #c9caca;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1px 8px 0 8px;
    position: relative;
    top:1px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: table` values, for example.

```
<style>
.ga_sep{
    height:10px;
    width:1px;
    border-left:1px solid #c9caca;
    margin:1px 8px 0 8px;
    position: relative;
    top:1px;
    display:inline;
}
div {display: table}
span {display: table-cell}
span:first-child {white-space: nowrap}
</style>

<div>
    <span style="color:#c9caca">Scope of Work</span>
    <span class="ga_sep"></span>
    <span>Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine Advertising, Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine, Advertising, Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine Advertising</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7hhx5qe/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use display inline-block like this..

Get rid of that border span also.. you don't need it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7hhx5qe/3/)

## html:

```
<span style="color:#c9caca">Scope of Work</span><span>Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine Advertising, Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine, Advertising, Idea Processing, Photography, Magazine Advertising</span>
```

## css:

```
span              { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
span:nth-child(1) { border-right:1px solid #c9caca; padding:0 8px 0 0; margin:0 8px 0 0; font:normal 13px arial;}
span:nth-child(2) { width:calc(100% - 103px);}
```

** Notice: I get 103px from calculating the overall width (width+padding+border+margin) of the first span.. If you don't know the width beforehand you could use percentage to a certain extent.. to get the absolute liquidity effect down to a very narrow width, in that case the answer above (display:table) might be more suitable.

Comment: You don´t know that first two spans have width of exactly 103px.

Comment: @panther You're right, though its reduced to 1 span, but this shows an example of how to do it, if the text is static.. you would know the exact width.. if dynamic just use percentage.. I'll update my answer thanks

Comment: No, you never know the text element width. You don't know if the same font is loaded, if user zoom the page, etc. When you want to change the text, you have to make change in CSS file too, etc. No, it's not the right way. You don't know neither the pixel width, nor the percent width. You know nothing about element containing text.

Comment: @panther Points taken. though just to be a devils advocate.. you also 'know nothing about element containing text' .. in your answer you assume these span's are wrapped by a div, which may or may not be the case.. depends how the html is generated.

Comment: In each situation I´m able to render a little but changed HTML. There are task which are impossible without changing HTML stucture. But I know that I can´t calculate with text element width/height so I do everything to changing HTML markup :-) Question is solved, PO got his answer.