# Sidebar menu title not showing properly in AdminLte

Tags: html, css, adminlte

In AdminLTE theme side bar menu title is not showing properly when the title is long, it breaks the line and show the text below the icon.
I want it to start below the first letter of first line 
I have attached screenshot for this
Here in the image "consetetur" should start from exact below the word "Lorem".

[image]

and here is my code for:

```
<li class="treeview">
<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
    <span style="padding-right: 50px;white-space: normal;line-height:14px">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
    </span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
</a>
<ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block">
                <div style="width:10%;float:left;padding-top: 5px;">
                    <i class=" fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> 
                </div>
                <div style="width:90%;float:right">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block">
                <div style="width:10%;float:left;padding-top: 5px;">
                    <i class=" fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> 
                </div>
                <div style="width:90%;float:right">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On using

```
a {  display: table} a>* {  display: table-cell;}
```

it shows

[image]

Text should start right next to the icon

Thanks.

Comment: Not a theory exam. Provide your code for further inspection.

Comment: Hi @amit77309 i have added please check and let me know if you get any issue

Comment: checkout 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954916/span-multiline-start-from-same-position?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi @amit77309 sorry it is not working properly, it is moving whole content to the new line and also moving arrow of the right side at the text end

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

1. Check your browser compatibility. For me it is working in chrome.
2. Check this small portion without using any extra html or css.
3. Check your css is overriding this styles.

```css
a {
  display: table
}

a>* {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
  <span >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod Lorem ipsum dolor sitLorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod Lorem ipsum dolor sitLorem ipsum dolor sit
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Hi @amit77309 you are 90% right. I have got the solution.

Comment: close this question

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution with the help of @amit77309.

Need to add following style:

```
.treeview > a {  display: table}
.treeview > a > *{  display: table-cell;}
```

Thanks.