# span multiline start from same position in admin lte

Tags: html, css, adminlte

Is it possible to start sidebar-menu title to be multi-lined and start at the same position of first line in the sidebar menu of adminlte theme.
I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954916/span-multiline-start-from-same-position?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it is not working properly, it is moving whole content to the new line and also moving arrow of the right side at the text end

Thanks.